# Cleaning up URLs. URLRewrite OR Redirect?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

I'm a bit stuck on how to clean up some URLs.  Here is what I have

```
mycompany.example/product1/Default.aspx?client=myClient&type=1
```

Something similar to that with a very much much longer querystring.

I would like to leave the files where they are, but when people type in the URL

```
myproductexample/product/
```

it actually show the page above (`mycompany.example`), without the customer ever knowing that the real page has a huge query string.

But then also when the customer request something like `myproductexample/product/image1.gif` or `myproductexample/product/search.aspx`, the site would also get the info from the mycompany website. (`mycompany.example/product1/image1.gif` and `mycompany.example/product1/search.aspx` respectively)

I thought that this wouldn't be soo hard with some URL rewrite filter or something, but I'm having a tough time because i'm using two different sites (mycompany.example and myproductexample), maybe this isn't possible?  I thought that this wouldn't be a big problem because they are stored on the same webserver with a directory structure like this.

```
Websites
    mycompany.example
         product1
    myproductexample
    myothersite.example
```

So my question is.  Is something like this possible with URLRewriting? or should I be looking towards something else to achieve what I want?  The reason I don't really want to simply redirect is because I don't want customers messing with the query string, it looks ugly, you'll never remember it, and I thought the search engine bots didn't like redirects.

Bonus:
If it is possible with URLRewriting, can someone give me some hints with the RewriteRules?  I'm new to Regular Expressions and having a hell of time even getting very small basic things working, let alone this.

Answer (score 0):

For URLs in the same domain you can use Server.Transfer. The browser address bar will retain the friendly URL, while on the server you will process your URL with the query string.

Assuming your different domains are on different servers, you won't be able to transfer between domains.

Check here for more info: http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite - Old post, but for the record.